# I have create Login app using Json PHP fileits loging bt unable to go to next screen or activity

Tags: php, android, json

Here is my JSON CODE

```
<?php
require '../db_connect.php';
if (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password']))
{
    $myusername = $_GET['username'];
    $mypassword = $_GET['password']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_registration WHERE (username = '$myusername' or email = '$myusername' or phone = '$myusername')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

    $response["VerifiedMember"] = array();
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $VerifiedMember = array();
        $id=$row['id'];
        $phone=$row['phone'];
        $reg_type=$row['register_type'];
        $stored_salt = $row['salt'];
        $stored_hash = $row['hashed_password'];
        $check_pass = $stored_salt . $mypassword;
        $check_hash = hash('sha512',$check_pass);

        if($check_hash == $stored_hash){

            $VerifiedMember['user_id'] = $id;
            $VerifiedMember['first_name']=$row['first_name'];
            $VerifiedMember['phone']=$row['phone'];
            array_push($response["VerifiedMember"], $VerifiedMember);

         if(!empty($phone)&& $reg_type==1){

             $sql="select * from user_otps where user_id='".$id."'";
             $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
             if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if($row['verified']==0)
                {
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "failure";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);

                }
                else
                {   
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 1;
                      $response["message"] = "success";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
             }
         }
         else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 1;
                      $response["message"] = "success";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
         }
         //echo json_encode($response);
        }

        else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "invalid";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "invalid";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is Android Code

```
public class NewLogin  extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

    String username;
    String password;
    String result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    }

    public void invokeLogin(View view) {
        new loginAccess().execute();
    }


    class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        String access;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewLogin.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();



        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            String url = "www.sample.com/home_webservice.php";
            JSONObject json = null;

            try {



                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
              Log.d("TESS :: ", json.toString());
                String status = json.getString("VerifiedMember");
         Log.d("Success Response :: ", status);


                if (status.equals("VerifiedMember")) {


                    Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, NEWClass.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
                else if
                      (json.getString("VerifiedMember").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("failed"))
                {

                    Toast.makeText(NewLogin.this, "Please enter the correct details!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block flag=1;

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, NEWClass.class);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the JSON I'm getting back:

{"VerifiedMember":[{"user_id":"23","first_name":"karan","phone":""}],"success":1,"message":"success"}

Unable to go new Activity after Login I m getting all users details correctly in LOG file bt not going to next activity 
please help me to solve  this 
thank you in advance..

Comment: is there any error you are getting ?

Comment: No sir no error getting alcorrect details from json file @GaneshPatil

Comment: What you will get in "status"?

Comment: add debugger where you are calling new activity and check

Comment: how to add debugger sry i m new in this area pls help and explain me in detail with example @GaneshPatil

Comment: Dont write  Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, NEWClass.class);
                    startActivity(i); in do in background method

Comment: are you sure NEWClass.class its activity?

Comment: so where should i write this line @RajeshNasit
yes its new class is and activity bt here i m using RecyclerView Holder where i want to go

Comment: First make sure you get the json response in your logcat and use intent in the onPost method

Comment: in on post execute method

Comment: I m getting json response in logcat successfully and i alredy use intent in onPOST method its work bt without editing or fillup details in form i login to next page without showing me error @RajeshNasit

Comment: So check in post execute your response condition and redirect if success otherwise set error and focus that editext without redirect. You just returen your response and catch in on post execute and perform operation what you want

Comment: can u write in my code i cnt understand properly wt u say exactly sorry i m new in andorid so pls help me @RajeshNasit

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
           JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response);
            if(jsonObject.getString("success").equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                //start new activity
            }else{
//error message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     public class NewLogin  extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

    String username;
    String password;
    String result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    }

    public void invokeLogin(View view) {
        new loginAccess().execute();
    }


    class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        String access;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewLogin.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();



        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            String url = "http://uat.ziplife.in/mobileapp/login_webservice.php";
            JSONObject json = null;

            try {



                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
              Log.d("TESS :: ", json.toString());
            JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response);
String status=jsonObject .getString("success")
if(status.equals("1)

                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, NEWClass.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
                else if

                {

                    Toast.makeText(NewLogin.this, "Please enter the correct details!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block flag=1;

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, NEWClass.class);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey did u get any solution buddy??

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your code try this

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            String url = "http://uat.ziplife.in/mobileapp/login_webservice.php";
            JSONObject json = null;

            try {



                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

                int successValue = json.getInt("success");






            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block flag=1;

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return String.valueOf(successValue);
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonstring) {
            pDialog.dismiss();


             if(jsonstring.equas("1")){
            Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, NEWClass.class);
            startActivity(i);
         }else{
              Toast.makeText(NewLogin.this, "Please enter the correct details!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: showing errror in this line   JsonObject jsonObject =  new JsonObject(jsonString);
               JsonArray array = jsonObject.getJsonArray("VerifiedMember");
             int success = jsonObejct.getInt("success"); @Sandeepdhiman

Comment: @karanbrahmaxatriya what error you are getting there?

Comment: jsonObject and getJsonArray showing me in red color could not reslove getJsonArray @sandeepdhiman

Comment: acept my answer if it helped you

Comment: Now i want to add logout button in new activtiy when user click on logout it logout from app and redirect to loging page please help me @Sandeepdhiman

Comment: in your NEWClass.class add a logout button and onclick of the button finish your NewClass activity you will be logged out

Comment: bt when agian open it open newClass activity page not login page @sandeepdhimen

Comment: show your code where you have put your logout code on button click

Comment: Use sharedpreference to store your login status once logged in and clear sharedpreference after log out

Comment: can u add in my code sorry i hve zero knowledge about sharedpreferece @Sandeepdhiman

Answer (score 1):

class loginAccess extends AsyncTask {

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    ProgressDialog   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewLogin.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Login...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


    String url = "http://uat.ziplife.in/mobileapp/login_webservice.php";
    JSONObject json = null;

    try {



        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        return jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block flag=1;

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    if(null!=response) {
        String status = response.getString("VerifiedMember");

        if (status.equals("VerifiedMember")) {

            Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, NEWClass.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if
                (json.getString("VerifiedMember").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("failed")) {

            Toast.makeText(NewLogin.this, "Please enter the correct details!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: showing me error in protected JSONObject doInbackground @RajeshNasit

Comment: Sir please help me to solve this issue please @RajeshNasit

Comment: check my asyncktask carefully and implement our one. I am not getting

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the JSON I'm getting back:

```
{"VerifiedMember":[{"user_id":"23","first_name":"karan","phone":""}],"success":1,"message":"success"}
```

Comment: you need to parse your json first and get success status

Comment: How to parse @GaneshPatil

Comment: pls check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Tutorial For JSON Parsing in Android,

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

```
JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response);  
if(jsonObject.getString("message").equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
{
            //start your activity
}else
{
           // Give a Message
}
```